# Return an array containing all of the result set rows as objects

Tags: php, arrays, angularjs, object, post

I'm trying to retrieve data from a mysql database with angular and php.

In angular I'm using the following code:

```
$http({ url: "http://domain.com/script.php",
                method: "POST",
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                data: $.param({clubid:$localStorage.choosenClub.ClubID})
            }).success(function(data) {

                console.log(data);

            }).error(function(data) {
                console.log("error:" + data);
            })
            .finally(function () {
                //Do something on finish
        });
```

In my PHP script I'm doing the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE club_id='$club'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);   

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo('[');
        echo json_encode($row);
        echo(']');
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

When I have one row with data in my mysql database the above code will provide me with a object in a array:

```
[{"event_id":"123456","club_id":"12345","organizer":"name","date":"2016-04-24","time":"08:00:00","title":"test title"}]
```

With the above result I'm able to retrieve de data with angular $http (code above) and I can populate it on my page with ng-repeat with no problems.

When I add more rows with data in my mysql database it is not working anymore.
For example when I have two rows with data in my mysql database the result looks like this:

```
[{"event_id":"123456","club_id":"12345","organizer":"name","date":"2016-04-24","time":"08:00:00","title":"test title"}][{"event_id":"98765","club_id":"526789","organizer":"name","date":"2016-04-24","time":"08:00:00","title":"test title"}]
```

And I get the following error in my console:

> Error: JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string parse@[native
>   code]

I think (correct me if i'm wrong) there is something wrong with formatting multiple rows of data.
When I have one row of data it is a object in a array, when I have more than one rows of data they are not objects in a array anymore.

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to build a json string yourself, php can do this for you. :)

First add all the rows to an array and then `json_encode` the array.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE club_id='$club'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);   

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
    $rows = [];       
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Add all rows to an array
        $rows[] = $row
    }

    // Json encode the full array
    echo json_encode($rows);
} else {

    echo "0 results";

}
```

Also, instead of echoing `0 results`, you should better echo `[]`, as this can be parsed by your json parser as an empty array.